# Whether a set is open and dense in $\mathfrak{C}[0,1]$

Tags: general-topology

Consider the space $X=\mathfrak{C}[0,1]$ with usual sup-norm topology. Let $$S=\left\{f\in X~:~\int_0^1f(x)dx\neq0\right\}$$

If for $f\in X$, $\int_0^1f(x)dx=I$, then we can show that $B_f(I/2)\subset S$. Hence $S$ is open.

Also if for $f\in X$, $\int_0^1f(x)dx=0$, then the sequence $\{f_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ defined as $f_n(x)=f(x)-\frac{1}{n}$ for $x\in[0,1]$, consists of elements in $S$ and converges to $f$ in sup-norm metric. Hence $S$ is also dense in $X$.

Are my statements correct?

Also I need to check whether $S$ is connected and $S^c$ is compact. Any kind of hints will be appreciated.

Comment: I think your statements are correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your work is correct.

**About the follow-up questions:**

$S$ is not connected: Think of the two parts $\{f\in X | \int f > 0\}$ and $\{f\in X | \int f < 0\}$.

$S^C$ is not compact: it isn't bounded (can you think of functions in $X$ that integrate to $0$ but have larger and larger sup-norms).